# How to create factor variable with unequal groups in R? Getting warning

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to create a factor variable with 3 groups: 0, 1-2, and 3+.

I was using the `cut` function to make unequal breaks:

```
set.seed(2) 
x <- rpois(n = 1000, lambda = 1.5) 

breaks <- c(0, 1, 2, 3:max(x))

cut(x, breaks = breaks, right = TRUE)


## But this gives me the following: 

Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,8]


## I tried this as well: 

breaks <- c(0, seq(1, 2, by = 1), 3:max(x))


## But that gives me: 

Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8]
```

edit:

The following gives me the correct levels:

```
breaks <- c(0, 1, 3, Inf) 
cut(x, breaks, right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE) 

Levels: [0,1) [1,3) [3,Inf]
```

But I am getting an error message that my level [2] is duplicated:

```
x.factor <- factor(x, levels = cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 3, Inf), right = FALSE, 
                                       include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Not sure where to go from here.. any ideas?

Comment: The `cut` returns a `vector` of the same `length` as 'x',  May be you need to wrap with `levels` i.e `grp <- cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 3, Inf), labels = c('0', '1-2', '3+'), right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)`and it is already a `factor` with the correct `labels`.

Comment: I didn't realize that the `cut` function could turn `x` into a factor variable without using the `factor` function over it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we can change the `breaks` with a large number at the end and specify the `labels`

```
grp <- cut(x, breaks = c(0:2, Inf), right = TRUE, 
        labels = c('0', '1-2', '3+'), include.lowest = TRUE)
levels(grp)
#[1] "0"   "1-2" "3+" 

head(x)
#[1] 0 2 2 0 4 4

head(grp)
#[1] 0   1-2 1-2 0   3+  3+ 
#Levels: 0 1-2 3+
```

Comment: It looks like `breaks = c(0:2, Inf)` creates the following levels: `[0, 1], (1, 2], (2, Inf]`. I'm trying to make levels '[0, 1), [1, 2], and [3, Inf]. I'm varying the breaks but still can't seem to get the right levels.

Comment: @user12310746  Please check the arguments `include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE` is by default.  You can change it

Comment: I think I got it: `cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 3, Inf), right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation pts to upvote/downvote

Comment: I updated my post -- do you have any suggestions to deal with the warning I'm getting? I've looked at previous posts but the `unique(cut(x))` solution doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: @user12310746  I am not sure why you need to change `x` as the 'grp' is already created as a separate vector with corresponding factor levels.  If you need some statistics, you can use a group by operation i.e `tapply(x, grp, FUN = mean)`